# change wireless network security key CMD or VBScript

Tags: powershell, vbscript, cmd, wireless

to see wireless network security key we can use this in cmd :

**netsh wlan show profile name="WIRELESS NAME" key=clear**

and to add profile we can use this :

**netsh wlan add profile filename=D:\file.xml**

I need a command to change the password for Wireless Networks profile

is there any scripting whay to do this ? ( vbsript - cmd - powershell )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `netsh` command for this purpose too.

If you run the following command, you can see the profile parameters you can set uting the netsh command:

```
netsh wlan set profileparameter /?
```

You'd use the name to identify, just as in your sample, and I guess you should use the `keyMaterial` parameter to set the password.